# mod_rewrite in .htaccess, go/*, go?, go?/* work, but go/?* doesn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried going through some of the mod_rewrite questions on the site, but didn't find an answer to my problem (the fact that most questions were titled "mod_rewrite doesn't work" didn't help make that task any easier, hopefully my title is a little more helpful).

this is the content of my /somepath/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^go/(.*) /cgi-bin/goto.cgi?$1
    # ^^^ WORKS: /somepath/go/200001..
RewriteRule ^go?(.*) /cgi-bin/goto.cgi$1
    # ^^^ WORKS:  /somepath/go?200001..


ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/goto.cgi?error404
```

In testing, I made goto.cgi simply return $ENV{QUERY_STRING}, $ENV{QUERY_STRING_UNESCAPED} and $ENV{PATH_INFO}. Currently, the above rules mean that I am getting the QUERY_STRING passed on correctly when the urls:

```
/somepath/go/200001
/somepath/go?200001
/somepath/go?/200001
```

are accessed, but not when

```
/somepath/go/?200001
```

is accessed, in which case $ENV{QUERY_STRING}, $ENV{QUERY_STRING_UNESCAPED} and $ENV{PATH_INFO} are empty.

So the question is, what rule can I use so that

```
/somepath/go/?200001
```

gives my script the ?200001 or even /?200001 part back?

Comment: For additional fun and confusion, go to `/somepath/getconfused` and wonder why the server complains that `/cgi-bin/goto.cgietconfused` does not exist ;-)

Comment: @Sumurai8 heh, yeah, I mentioned that problem in the comments to the answer given. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule is destroying the query string of the example that fails, since `$1` will be empty and an empty query string in the substitution removes any existing query string.

And the second rule is gibberish.

```
RewriteRule ^go/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/goto.cgi?$1
RewriteRule ^go/?$ /cgi-bin/goto.cgi
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly, it gives me the right results for the above mentioned urls, but it also redirects things like /somepath/go200001 to my script, where it should just be a 404, how can this be fixed?

Comment: The change fixes the /somepath/go200001 problem, but causes the /somepath/go/?200001 to no longer work (gives me a 404 result)

Comment: Perfect! Now it works! I also added the [QSA,L] flags in order to get some other things working. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your answer also helps me understand how apache treats these requests, so thanks for that too.